# how to calculate with varchar, null

Tags: sql-server

I want to calculate with a value but i keep getting the message in SQL Server

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '10,0000' to data type int.

Or this one:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1.8' to data type int.

This is the query that i want to use.

```
SELECT DISTINCT   CTPARAM
                , WAARDEBEG
                , CASE 
                      WHEN CTPARAM = 'CPERCTARLG' THEN 100 - WAARDEBEG
                      WHEN CTPARAM = 'CPERCTARHG' THEN 100 + WAARDEBEG
                  END AS Percentage
                , _Id

  FROM WinIKAZ.CTE10
 WHERE  CTCMPTYPE = 'TF'
   AND  (DATAFVOER = 0 OR DATAFVOER >= 20180101)
   AND  (CTPARAM = 'CPERCTARLG' OR CTPARAM = 'CPERCTARHG')
   AND  DATIN < 20190101
   AND  WAARDEBEG NOT IN ('0,0000', '0')
   AND  _Id in (3644846, 3309750, 3062876)
```

WAARDEBEG has 3 values

(10,0000), (1.8) and (10)

it only works with the (10) value.

How do I convert the WAARDEBEG so I can calcuate with the 10,0000 and 1,8 values

Comment: What decimal and thousand separator are you storing in the WAARDEBEG column? Is `1.8` stored as `1,8`?

Comment: Add  REPLACE ( WAARDEBEG , ',' , '.' )

Comment: The better question is, why are you storing numerical data as a `varchar` in the first place? Numerical data should be stored using a numerical data type (i.e. `int` and `decimal`). What number does `'10,0000'` represent? Normally the commas are thousand, million, etc, separators, so your value would be `'100,000'`; you're comma is therefore in the wrong place. This the comma playing the role of a decimal point (so should be `10.0000`)?

Comment: 1,8 is stored as 1.8. I totally agree that storing numerical data as a varchar is not the way to go. But that's out of my hands. 10,000 represents 10.

Comment: If I use the replace function like this:

 case 
    when CTPARAM = 'CPERCTARLG' then 100 - REPLACE(WAARDEBEG,',','.')
    when CTPARAM = 'CPERCTARHG' then 100 + REPLACE(WAARDEBEG,',','.')
    end as Percentage

I still get the message
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1.8' to data type int.